# Local SqlServer Database connection for API tests in azure devops pipeline build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, web-api-testing, sql-server-2019

I have a .Net Core 3.0 API and
a sql server 2019 database, running on the machine I develop on.
I have 2 API tests that need to connect to db, passing in visual studio test explorer

But on azure devops my pipeline build fails on those 2 API tests
I have set sqlserver for sharedmemory, named pipes and tcp/ip
did not change port 1433
have enabled remote connections in sql server
made a login and a schema for database login
connected my ssms through sql server authentication
have used the vs2019 sql server object explorer properties tab on the database to get the connection string for the db connected with sql server authentication
have stopped and restarted all sql services at regular times. Also my windows firewall is disconnected))

the failing build task in yml

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Running Tests'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
```

get following error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40
        - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
        ---- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The network path was not found.
```

connectionstring:

```
"Data Source=LAPTOP-SOMERANDOM-NAME;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=Admin;Password=*****;
Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

And if I add the port '1433' after Data Source I get following error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)
---- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No such host is known.
```

Can I make it work?
Do I need a clone of my db of some sort in my pipeline?

Unfortunately I don't have a credit card and no more free credits for azure resource groups
also I don't work with keyvault, I'm trying to make the connection first, will make it safer later :)

Big Thanks in advance for reading and helping!

Comment: Did you try to reach your machine outside of the your network?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej No, thank you for the pointer, I'm looking into it atm, but it's all new for me, so might take some time! I'll let you know how it goes but thank you already! I'll try and find my ip adress and port to use instead of machinename in the connectionstring)